# How to read events in Google calendar?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I am new to Android Studio and I would like to know how I can read the calendar events of a specific Gmail account (i.e. the default account) from my app.
I would like something like that when I open the `eventActivity` in my app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage your schedule in a calendar, you can integrate Google Calendar, check [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java). This is a tutorial showing you how to integrate it.

It also contains the sample project in Java and others language.